# How do I maintain formatting of comments when I save them to the database in an asp.net mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The title was probably not very clear. Consider this scnerio: you have a blog site or really just any site where a user can respond via a comment. You want to maintain the formatting for the comments. So paragraph's should be separated, first sentence indented, bolding of keywords allowed, etc. How would one go about doing this?

This is something just about every kind of blogging site handles, including this site. My initial guess is that comments are saved to that database either in an xml format or as the raw html. Those are really my only guesses. I suppose magic strings could be used to denote the starting and ending of various formatting as well, but magic strings are generally frowned upon.

I'm doing this in an asp.net mvc application. I'm using version 1 of mvc, but I would be willing to move to 2 if that makes for an easy solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Look into [Markdown](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/markdown_announced.aspx).

Longer answer: The formatting of text is preserved when committed to a database, but will not appear properly when displayed in a web page unless text formatting elements such as carriage returns (CR) and linefeeds (LF) are converted to HTML.

Comment: Any thoughts on how exactly to detect where the carriage returns and linefeeds are in a textbox/textarea when the comment is submitted? ASP.NET MVC will bind the CommentText to my Comment object during the submit so I'm afraid I'll just get one condensed paragraph of text without formatting on the server end.

Comment: If you enter comments into a multiline textbox (as I'm doing right now) and include CRLF by hitting enter, that will be in the value posted to the server.  If you bind that text to an object, the CRLF will be there, and you'll see it if you put the text back into a textarea, but not if you feed it out as HTML... You might also look into a rich-text editor like FCKEditor if you're concerned with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This is really implementation specific, but more than likely they are storing the raw html or using magic strings.

And magic strings aren't really frowned upon, especially in certain scenarios (discussion boards like phpBB for instance that uses BBCode) where you are protecting the users viewing the info as much as preventing them from hacking your DB or website.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sound feasible to me. I would like to point out however, that before you save any HTML code to a DB it needs to be sanitized.

You will need some truly paranoid code to remove the nasty bits some miscreants insist upon trying to post...

one approach could be to convert legal HTML tags to mark down (as another answer suggests) and strip the rest ruthlessly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do.

I use [Jeff's Sanatize Code](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html) (in ASP.NET MVC as a `Html.Helper`).  The code is saved to the Database as the user wrote it, but it's displayed on the screen with the sanatize in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this text editor we are using, go to http://wmd-editor.com/. Configure it to output Markdown and save to the database.

If you need more power you can use FCKEditor, CKEditor(new FCKEditor), http://ckeditor.com/, its very easy to setup and they will put a nice javascript WYSIWYG editor on your page and you will save HTML to your database.

One drawback is that you will need take care of malicious users with javascript attacks like cross site scripting. You should sanitize the user input before saving it to the database.

Microsoft released http://antixss.codeplex.com/ AntiXSS that should help sanitize user input.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow a View to keep line-breaks from database:

```
@Html.Raw(item.YourField.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "< br/ >"))
```

or you can use < pre >

```
< pre > @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.YourField) < / pre >
```